# Calculate length of paths with defined vertexes

Tags: qgis-3, route, vertices, length

I'd like to calculate length of some paths with defined vertexes and each route is characterized by some records.

For example, I need the length of all combinations of lines (AB, BC, CD, AD, AC, BD).

Is there a Geoprocessing tool or QGIS Plug-in to do this, avoiding merging the records of the single path manually?

[image: example]

Comment: Are your lines a one(single) feature or they are already split on vertices, e.g. many features in a shapefile?

Comment: There is a single shapefile splitted on vertices and characterized by many records (without relation field). The output should be a shapefile with 6 features with the field "length", and these will be obviously overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have two layers `"vertices"` and `"paths"` with its corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to calculate length of some paths with defined vertexes and each route is characterized by some records.

```sql
SELECT p.geometry AS geom,
       v1.Name AS "from_point",
       v2.Name AS "to_point",
       round(st_length(p.geometry),4) AS "path_length"
FROM "paths" AS p
LEFT JOIN "vertices" AS v1 ON st_touches(p.geometry, v1.geometry)
LEFT JOIN "vertices" AS v2 ON st_touches(p.geometry, v2.geometry)
WHERE v1.id <> v2.id
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

*Notes:*

- The output layer will contain some geometry twice, i.e. path `1->2` is the same as `2->1`
- This approach will only work when paths are broken at vertices and vertices are snapped to paths